# Pybuilder - Non-python files are not packaged

Tags: python-3.x, distutils, pybuilder

My current project is in python. For build package generation + unit test running, I'm using **Pybuilder** utility and it is pretty cool. I used the **wheel distribution** to install the module in other systems.

There exist a config file from which certain settings are read by the application. settings.ini file is in following path,

```
PROJECT-ROOT
     |---- src
            |-main
                |-python
                     |- foo
                         |- conf
                         |   |- settings.ini
                         |
                         |-test.py
                         |-access.py
```

pybuilder automatically creates setup.py from the build.py script. The problem is that **the binary wheel distribution is not packaging the non-python files(*.ini file)**. While searching on SO posts, got information like adding in MANIFEST.mf will resolve this issue. But while adding

```
 project._manifest_include_directory('foo/conf', ('*.ini',))
```

It only updated `foo/conf/settings.ini` in sdist and not on the bdist(wheel). I **want the wheel file to include settings.ini in the conf/ directory**. On googling, got information that addition of  `package_data` field in setup.py will resolve this issue. But with Pybuilder's build.py, I'm unable to do this successfully.

Can any one help me to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've emailed Max(https://github.com/mriehl), who is one among the contributor of PyBuilder code in github. He suggested me to try  `project.install_file()` option.

I tried that option and it worked for me. Thanks to Max. I want to share that info in this thread, so that it will be useful to someone in future !

In the background `project.install_file()` is modifying `data_files` part of `setup.py` of **distutils**.

My configuration in the `build.py` are as follows,

```
@init
def initialize (project):

    # File is installed relative to sys.prefix
    project.install_file("Lib/site-packages/foo/conf","foo/conf/settings.ini")
```

Comment: I am stuck to same issue, tried both include_file and project.package_data.update({'mypkg': [/rel/path/to/file]}) but not able to add files as package data in binary distribution.