# How to include datasets in packages generated by PyBuilder and make them available

Tags: python-3.x, pybuilder

I'm experimenting with PyBuilder because I'm looking for a more organised and production-oriented way of developing data science projects.

So far, I've created a PyBuilder project with the following structure (folder are uppercased for readability):

```
PROJECT
 |   build.py
 |   setup.py
 +-- .ENV
 |   +-- ...
 +-- SRC
 |   +-- MAIN
 |   |   +-- FIXTURES
 |   |   |   +-- data.csv
 |   |   +-- PYTHON
 |   |   |   +-- code.py
 |   |   +-- SCRIPTS
 |   |       +-- run.py
 |   +---TEST
 |       +-- FIXTURES
 |       |   +-- values.csv
 |       +-- PYTHON
 |           +-- test_code.py
...
```

`build.py` and `setup.py` are PyBuilder generated files. 
`.env` contains the virtual environment (i.e.: Python 3.7).
`src\main` and `src\test` have the usual structure apart from the fact that each contain a new `fixtures` folder (much like `resources` in Java). If you wonder, `src\test` looks as stated because:

```
project.set_property("dir_source_unittest_python", "src/test/python")
project.set_property("unittest_module_glob", "test_*")
```

My intent is as follows:

- `run.py` contains a script that calls the code in `code.py` to predict tomorrow's weather, for instance
- `code.py` contains the code to load the dataset in `data.csv` and build a model that provides weather's predictions for a given day.
- `data.py` contains the historical data that is needed in `code.py` to train the weather forecasting model
- `test_code.py` contains the unit tests to make sure that the model and utility functions in `code.py` work as expected
- `values.py` contains the input values and expected results to be used in `test_code.py` to test `code.py`.

My code in `code.py` accesses `data.csv` by defining the FIXTURES folder as follows:

```
FIXTURES = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..', 'fixtures')
...
with open(os.path.join(FIXTURES, 'data.csv'), 'r') as file:
    ...
```

And I can successfully run the script `run.py` from within my IDE to generate predictions.

When I try to generate a package to share the predictor with my colleagues, I see that the `src\main\fixtures` folder is not copied over. After some research ([see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37409282/pybuilder-non-python-files-are-not-packaged)), I managed to amend this by:

1. Moving the `fixtures` folder into `python`
2. Adding `project.include_file("lib/python3.7/site-packages/fixtures", "fixtures/*.csv")` to `build.py`.

Unfortunately, I would like to keep `fixtures` where it was initially. I've noticed anyway that `run.py` fails to execute even though the installation terminates successfully (`pyb install`). The reason is that `data.csv` can't be successfully located:

```
... 
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] File b'/Users/stefano/Workspace/project/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/../fixtures/data.csv' does not exist: b'/Users/stefano/Workspace/project/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/../fixtures/data.csv'
```

**Does anyone know how to keep the `fixtures` folder in `src\main` (rather than in `src\main\python`)?**

**Also, does anyone know how to make files like `data.csv` discoverable after package installation?**

Thanks in advance for any help!

**Note:** *Please be aware that a solution using this structure might not be the most convenient one if the `data.csv` is quite big.*

Comment: Where you able to figure this out? I am in the same boat as well. @Stefano Bragaglia

Comment: Hi Gopinath, see my answer below. It worked for me...

Answer (score 1):

I eventually discovered [this part](https://pybuilder.readthedocs.io/en/latest/customizing-the-build.html#installing-files) of the original documentation suggesting the following solution that works fine with me:

```
use_plugin("copy_resources")
...
@init
def set_properties(project):
    project.get_property("copy_resources_glob").append("src/main/fixtures/*.csv")
    project.set_property("copy_resources_target", "$dir_dist")
    project.install_file("lib/python3.7/fixtures", "src/main/fixtures/data.csv")
```

**Note:** *In the last command, for some reason, it is not possible to use a wildcard (`project.install_file("lib/python3.7/fixtures", "src/main/fixtures/*.csv")`).*